# How can I define Settings and Analyzer for ElasticSearch?

Tags: spring, grails, elasticsearch, grails-2.0

I am using Grails with the [ElasticSearch Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch). It works fine, but I need to define the settings and analyzer.

How can I do that?

I want to use the following settings and mappings:

```
{
 "settings" : {
   "index" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
         "autocomplete" : "engram", 
         "filter" : ["lowercase"]
       }
     },
     "tokenizer" : {
        "engram" : {
          "type" : "edgeNgram", 
          "min_gram" : 3,
          "max_gram" : 10
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "contacts" : {
      "name" : {
        "index" : "string",
        "index_analyzer" : "autocomplete",
        "index" : "analyzed", "search_analyzer" : "standard"
      },
      "country" : { "type" : "string" }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](http://smaldini.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/docs/guide/3.%20Mapping.html#3.3%20Properties%20mapping) here. Keep a note, you would not be able to use nGram filters in [analyzers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/). In that case you have to use the dependency as is instead of the plugin.

Comment: @dmahapatro I have updated my question. You can see the things I want to implement. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I fear you cannot do that using the plugin, that is why I indicated in your earlier questions to use elastic search directly and not use the plugin. On the other hand, if you only want to create the mapping in your local elastic server, then go ahead and use REST PUT for the above json, that should create the analyzers. (Use curl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dmahaptro suggests, using Elasticsearch's Rest API would work. From http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-create-index/ under the "mappings" header, you can copy and paste the following into your shell:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index_name -d '{
"settings" : {
   "index" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
         "autocomplete" : "engram", 
         "filter" : ["lowercase"]
       }
     },
     "tokenizer" : {
        "engram" : {
          "type" : "edgeNgram", 
          "min_gram" : 3,
          "max_gram" : 10
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "contacts" : {
      "name" : {
        "index" : "string",
        "index_analyzer" : "autocomplete",
        "index" : "analyzed", "search_analyzer" : "standard"
      },
      "country" : { "type" : "string" }
    }
   }
  }
}'
```

A way to check that your index was created with the correct settings is to use the head plugin: https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head. Fire up the head plugin in your browser and click the "Cluster State" tab for all of your indexes and their settings, mappings, etc.