# Adding custom analyzer to elasticsearch via grails plugin

Tags: grails, elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to add a custom analyzer to elasticsearch via grails plugin. I was able to change the used analyzer to a common analyzer using "searchable" on the domain:

```
static searchable = {
        all = [analyzer: 'snowball']
    }
```

but cannot get it to know a costum analyzer. It is unclear how to translate the following json in the REST API to a groovy closue:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym", 
          "synonyms": [ 
            "british,english",
            "queen,monarch"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter" 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756102/elasticsearch-groovy-index-template#) question seems to have the same problem but the answer doesn't work, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188370/how-can-i-define-settings-and-analyzer-for-elasticsearch) answer suggests that it might not be possible, but that doesn't seem reasonable because setting a custom analyzer is pretty basic.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I see which would help you achieve that.

The first way is by going through the [low level API](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/lowLevelAPI.html) using the injected `elasticSearchHelper` and accessing ES client directly.

```
    elasticSearchHelper.withElasticSearch { client ->
        // Do some stuff with the ElasticSearch client
        client.admin()
            .indices()
            .prepareCreate(indexName)
            .setSettings(settings)       <--- your settings/analyzers go here
            .execute()
            .actionGet()
    }
```

A second way involves using an undocumented feature of the [`ElasticSearchAdminService` service](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/admin.html), namely the [`createIndex()` method](https://github.com/noamt/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugins/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchAdminService.groovy#L194-L208), which allows you to pass in the settings and analyzers you need when creating a new index. The latter basically does exactly the same as the first option above, but you get to use the Grails service directly.

Comment: Could you please explain the `setSettings(settings)` a bit further? I'm trying this approach and don't see what to insert exactly.

Comment: @FeinesFabi feel free to create a new question with details concerning your issue.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004164/how-to-filter-out-broken-html-tags-in-elasticsearchs-highlights